# Post-processing grep and pssh - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I do grep on a command and get the return value as follows:

```
HOST_NAME
IP
HOST_NAME
IP
...
```

HOST_NAME and IP are pairs.

I have to pass the IP to pssh and get the status

```
[SUCCESS] IP
[SUCCESS] IP
...
```

The final output of my command to be:

```
HOST_NAME IP [SUCCESS]
HOST_NAME IP [SUCCESS]
...
```

The issue I have is, if I write the output of grep to a file and then pssh, I am getting status for both HOST_NAME and IP which is reduntant.

If I get only the IP from grep and get the status, then I lose on the mapping between the IP and HOST_NAME.

How do I go about solving this in shell command?

Comment: Could you please do add what you have tried so far to solve this problem? Always try to do so in your posts.

Comment: You can use awk to get every other line, as explained in https://superuser.com/questions/101756/show-only-odd-lines-with-cat